# Управление динамической памятью в С++

Tags: c++, классы, инициализация

Подскажите есть ли правила хорошего тона или общепринятые соглашения по управлению динамической памятью в C++.

Например есть класс

```
class SomeData {
private:
  char* internalString_;
public:
          SomeData(char * internalString);
}
```

Как правильно реализовать конструктор? Класс должен сам выделить память и скопировать в нее строку?

```
SomeData::SomeData( char* internalString ) {
    internalString_ = new char[strlen(internalString)+1];
    *internalString_ = '\0';
    strcpy( internalString_, internalString);
}
```

Или можно оставить выделение памяти за тем кто вызывает конструктор? Вот так:

```
SomeData::SomeData( char* internalString ) {
    internalString_ = internalString;
}
```

И что делать если это будет не строка а более сложный объект, которые еще как то инициализировать необходимо?

Если можно и так и так, то в каких случаях какой политики придерживаться?

Comment: *"есть ли правила хорошего тона"* Не использовать `new` вообще. В крайнем случае, только внутри самописных контейнеров и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите - если выделяет кто-то другой, то кто должен освобождать память? Если деструктор - то вы не защищены от того, чтоб не передать случайно адрес массива. Если самостоятельно - надо отслеживать, что все объекты уже уничтожены, и не забыть освободить.

Поэтому *в общем случае* (исключения, подтверждающие правило, всегда возможны) используется [идиома RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) - захват ресурса есть инициализация (а деструкция - освобождение).

Так что *в общем случае* забирайте ресурсы в конструкторе, а освобождайте в деструкторе.

Comment: Мысль в целом понята. Кода речь идет о внутреннем элементе класса мы конструкторе обязательно создаем копию и следим за ее жизненным циклом.  Освобождаем память в деструкторе, следим за копированием и т.д.
Вопрос наверное чуть шире. Есть шаблоны проектирования когда к объекту надо относиться как к внутреннему объекту класса, а когда это просто ссылка? На объект со своим жизненным циклом?

Comment: Конечно, бывают и такие варианты - потому я и подчеркивал "в общем случае". Вообще в программировании, пожалуй, нет догм, и всегда надо руководствоваться здравым смыслом, тем более что практически любая задача может быть решена множеством способов. В этом случае просто нужно постараться - желательно на уровне языковых средств - не допустить ситуации со ссылкой на уже мертвый объект, а равно утечки ресурсов. Только и всего. И вообще, любой совет может превратиться со временем в противоположность :) - с развитием языка и компиляторов то, что считалось плюсом, легко может стать минусом...

Answer (score 1):

В общем, если у вас в классе есть указатель или ссылька, то  в обязательном порядке определите деструктор(освобождать память), конструктор копирования(копировать не указатель, а обьект, на который указывает он), оператор присваивания(присвоить указатель или обьект?...)... Если хотите придерживаться правилам хорошего тона. И ваш класс как минимум  будет выглядеть так:

```
class SomeData {
private:
  char* internalString_;
public:
          SomeData(char * internalString);
          SomeData(const SomeData&);
          SomeData& operator =(const SomeData&);
          ~SomeData() { delete [] internalString_; }
};
```

А вот в первом определении вашего конструктора наблюдаю ошибку:

```
*internalString_ = '\0';
```

Зачем первому сиволу присваивать символ конца строки?... Просто убрать эту строку

А еще лучше вместо указателей хранить умный указатель, или, для вашего случая, обьект std::string, тогда не нужно будет заморачиваться с копированием и уничтожением

Comment: ```наблюдаю ошибку``` - а в чем ошибка?

Comment: ошибка заключается в попытке присваивать первому символу массива символ конца строки.  Правда, вы потом копируете другой символ(весь массив  ) строкой    strcpy( internalString_, internalString);. Поэтому строка  *internalString_ = '\0';    становится просто лишней

Comment: Но в этом нет ошибки. Это гарантирует, что когда Вы попытаетесь прочесть данные из этой строки - это не приведет к тому, что Вы прочтете мусор, потому как в самом начале наткнетесь на 0.

Comment: Пруф: https://ideone.com/mrY87l

Comment: Для каждого особого случая есть свои финты, но это не значит, что этот финт правилен всегда. Конкретно вы пытаетесь инициализировать член класса и конкретно в этом случаи   не зачем запрещать читать, а следующим ходом присвоить другую строку.  Можно с тем же успехом написать *internalString_ = 0; а потом присвоить адрес обьекта. Смысль?...

Comment: В этом случае может и не надо. Это скорее привычка - инициализировать строку перед тем как что то с ней делать. Потому что если на следующем шаге вместо strcpy был бы strcat, то уже были бы проблемы.

Comment: >А еще лучше вместо указателей хранить умный указатель, или, для вашего случая, обьект std::string

Comment: @snullxbh,  Ваш пример вообше ниочем не говорит.  У вас указатель  ch  хранит адрес массива, и  ch != 0  всегда является истиной. Ваш цикл просто завершится на  256 ом ходу. Ну и что?...

Comment: Ой, простите, тут я забагался :)

Comment: Пример я привел не корректный, к тому же я даже написал его с ошибками. Пожалуйста, не обращайте внимание. И извините меня за мою невнимаьельность. В представленном примере это делать незачем, ок, но Вы называете это ошибкой. А я называю это средством предосторожности, хотя оно в _данном_ случае и излишне.